# Create menu from UL List with JQuery and JSON external file

Tags: jquery, json, list, menu, html-lists

I have a problem with creating menu using UL LI List and JQuery with JSON.
Here is my JFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/TqcEs/

```
    $.getJSON('http://www.speedyshare.com/zr6HF/download/doc22.json', function (data) {

    //$("body div#content").html(makeUL(data.menu[0]));
    $("body .menu ").html(makeUL(data.menu));

});
//$("body div#content").html("</li></ul>");

function makeUL(lst) {
    var html = [];
    //html.push("<div class=sub"+count+">");
    html.push("<ul>");
    count++;
    $(lst).each(function () {
        html.push(makeLI(this));
    });
    html.push("</ul>");
    //html.push("</div>");
    return html.join("\n");

}

function makeLI(elem) {
    var html = [];

    html.push("<li >");

    //html.push(elem.name);
    if (elem.link)
    //html.push("<div class=item"+count2+">");
    html.push("<a>" + elem.link + "</a>");
    //html.push("</div>");
    count2++;

    if (elem.sub) html.push(makeUL(elem.sub));
    html.push("</li>");
        //
        return html.join("\n");

}
```

In $.getJSON currently is direct link to JSON file, but he isn't working in JSFiddle(I don't know why), with external file on hard disk , works good.

Ok, I would like to do similar menu such as in this JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/65R8q/31/ ,but with data from my JSON file.  I tried around div's in many ways, but still not working. :-/

someone know where I do make mistake?

Comment: [**Same origin policy**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) !

Answer (score 1):

As adeneo commented, it's due to Same Origin Policy. You need to use [JSONP](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp) when making the Ajax code. Add `callback=?` parameter to the calling URL:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.speedyshare.com/zr6HF/download/doc22.json?callback=?', function (data) {

    //$("body div#content").html(makeUL(data.menu[0]));
    $("body .menu ").html(makeUL(data.menu));

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TqcEs/1/

But the page you are requesting is HTML, not JSON data so a syntax/JavaScript error thrown.